# Why doesn't this C# casting example work?

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I'm trying to understand why this cast doesn't work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CastTest {

    class Foo {}

    // I want to use this kind of like a typedef, to avoid writing List<Foo> everywhere.
    class FooList : List<Foo> {}

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            FooList list = (FooList) Program.GetFooList();
        }

        // Suppose this is some library method, and i don't have control over the return type
        static List<Foo> GetFooList() {
            return new List<Foo>();
        }
    }
}
```

This generates a runtime error:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CastTest.Foo]' to type 'CastTest.FooList'.

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work, and whether I can get around this somehow?

Comment: Which line generates the error?

Comment: Which is correct to say: A FooList is a List<Foo>, or a List<Foo> is a FooList?

Comment: If you don't like extra typing, use implicitly typed variables. Like this: `var list = Program.GetFooList();`

Comment: What's the big problem with writing `List<Foo>` everywhere? I once worked with a codebase that strongly typed lists and it was a major pain.

Comment: @eouw0o83hf, it's not really a problem to write List<Foo> everywhere, but I just came up with that as a contrived example for illustrative purpose.  I'm really trying to typedef much longer typenames (like dictionaries of lists)

Comment: Ah - well, the `using` alias may be your best friend in this case then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot automatically cast from a parent class to a derived class: just because the object you're attempting to cast is a `List<Foo>` doesn't necessarily make it a `FooList`.

Check out:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/csharplanguage/thread/f7362ba9-48cd-49eb-9c65-d91355a3daee

You could write an operator that converts a `List<Foo>` to a `FooList`, perhaps using `AddRange` to populate the values, such as:

```
class FooList
{
 public explicit operator FooList(List<Foo> arg)
 {
   FooList result = new FooList();
   result.AddRange(arg);
   return result;
  }
}
```

**Also, it may be better to just use a `using` alias**:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423(v=vs.80).aspx

```
using FooList = List<Foo>;
```

This way you're not actually passing around needless derived classes.

Comment: Thanks, and using `using` is a good tip... my only problem with it (and the reason I was trying to use classes to get around it) is that one `using` cannot depend on a type defined in another `using`.  Pair that with the fact that `using` needs to use a fully qualified typename (i.e., you need to use `System.Collections.Generic.List` rather than `List`) and `using` declarations get real wordy real fast.

Answer (score 7):

Just because your FooList is a List doesn't make the List a FooList.

Answer (score 4):

This method:

```
static List<Foo> GetFooList() {
    return new List<Foo>();
}
```

... doesn't return a `FooList`. Your code is effectively like this:

```
FooList list = (FooList) new List<Foo>();
```

That's simply not going to work. It's as invalid as:

```
string x = (string) new object();
```

You wouldn't expect that to work, would you? So why would your `FooList` version work?

Answer (score 2):

The closest C# has to a typedef is called a using alias directive:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CastTest {
    using FooList = List<Foo>;

    class Foo {}

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            FooList list = Program.GetFooList();
        }

        // Suppose this is some library method, and i don't have control over the return type
        static List<Foo> GetFooList() {
            return new List<Foo>();
        }
    }
}
```

What you have creates a derived class `FooList`, but this creates an alias `FooList`. It isn't somewhat compatible with `List<Foo>`, it **is** `List<Foo>`.

Answer (score 2):

Because not all List are FooList. For example, I could have:

```
public class AnotherFooList : List<Foo>
{
    public object AdditionalPropery {get; set; }
}
```

It too inherits from List but is not the same as a FooList and a FooList is not the same as it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that a `FooList` is in reality just another name for a `List<Foo>` it may seem strange. But given that a `FooList` could contain members itself, it becomes apparant that the compiler should not allow the cast. Imagine you at a later time introduce a method (`Bar()`) on the `FooList`. This method is not present on `List<Foo>` and the type system would simply break if the assignment (or cast) was allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You cant upcast; but you could create a new instance of FooList and the contents to it

```
class Foo { }

    // I want to use this kind of like a typedef, to avoid writing List<Foo> everywhere.
    class FooList : List<Foo> {}

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FooList l = new FooList();
            l.AddRange(GetFooList().Select(foo => foo));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // Suppose this is some library method, and i don't have control over the return type
        static List<Foo> GetFooList()
        {
            return new List<Foo>();
        }
    }
```